# TcpListener doesn't accept TcpClient

Tags: c#, sockets

The below code is Microsoft's code sample for **TcpListener** but I can't run that:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

public class TcpListenerSample
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // set the TcpListener on port 13000
            int port = 13000;
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);

            // Start listening for client requests
            server.Start();

            // Buffer for reading data
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            string data;

            //Enter the listening loop
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                int i;

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                while (i != 0)
                {
                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Received: {0}", data));

                    // Process the data sent by the client.
                    data = data.ToUpper();

                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                    // Send back a response.
                    stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Sent: {0}", data));

                    i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }

                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to continue...");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The code is stay into the loop in this line:

```
TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
```

I've turned the firewall off but nothing changed.

How can I solve this?

Comment: have you tried to connect to this server?

Comment: You could take a look at this question, maybe that helps you to find your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19476156/2865804

Comment: It should "stay" at that line until you connect to port 13000. You can easily try this while it is "staying" there by starting a command prompt and issuing telnet 127.0.0.1 13000 on the same machine. (You should have telnet client installed. How to install it is out of scope). It should then proceed to the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AcceptTcpClient()` is a blocking call which will block until a client has connected to your `TcpListener`. Therefore you need to use some kind of client application to test your server and connect to it. You could use [Putty](http://www.putty.org/) for this.